# Наложение водяного знака относительно размера исходного изображения

Tags: php, веб-программирование, изображения

У меня есть скрипт, чтобы при добавлении картинок в папку, на них автоматически накладывался водяной знак, но проблема в том, что картинки на сайте разные от 170х80 до 1000х600. Водяной знак имеет размеры 300х150 и при наложении размеров не меняет, то есть маленькие картинки затмевает. Собственно вопрос, как сделать, чтобы водяной знак ресайзился, а потом наклалывался?!

```
<?
waterMark($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 
"watermark.png", "bottom=5,right=5");

function waterMark($original, $watermark, $placement = 'bottom=5,right=5', 
$destination = null) {
 $original = urldecode($original);
 $info_o = @getImageSize($original);
 if (!$info_o)
    return false;
 $info_w = @getImageSize($watermark);
 if (!$info_w)
    return false;

 list ($vertical, $horizontal) = split(',', $placement,2);
 list($vertical, $sy) = split('=', trim($vertical),2);
 list($horizontal, $sx) = split('=', trim($horizontal),2);

 switch (trim($vertical)) {
    case 'bottom':
        $y = $info_o[1] - $info_w[1] - (int)$sy;
        break;
    case 'middle':
        $y = ceil($info_o[1]/2) - ceil($info_w[1]/2) + (int)$sy;
        break;
    default:
        $y = (int)$sy;
        break;
 }

 switch (trim($horizontal)) {
    case 'right':
        $x = $info_o[0] - $info_w[0] - (int)$sx;
        break;
    case 'center':
        $x = ceil($info_o[0]/2) - ceil($info_w[0]/2) + (int)$sx;
        break;
    default:
        $x = (int)$sx;
        break;
 }

 header("Content-Type: ".$info_o['mime']);
 //получаем оригинал картинки и водный знак
 $original = @imageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($original));
 $watermark = @imageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($watermark));
 //Подготавливаем пустое изображение
 $out = imageCreateTrueColor($info_o[0],$info_o[1]);
 $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 50);
 $width = imagesx($watermark);
 $height = imagesy($watermark);
 imagecopyresized($thumb, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, 
 $width, $height);
 //Накладываем оригинал на подготовленное изображение
 imageCopy($out, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $info_o[0], $info_o[1]);

 //Тут задаем размер изображения в которые можно добавлять Watermark
 // $info_o[0] > 250 - ширина изображения должна быть больше 250 px
 // $info_o[1] > 250 - высота изображения должна быть больше 250 px

 if( ($info_o[0] > 250) && ($info_o[1] > 250) )
 {
    //Накладываем водный знак на оригинал
    imageCopy($out, $thumb, $x, $y, 0, 0, $info_w[0], $info_w[1]);
 }
 //Выводим изображение в случаях с разными форматами
 switch ($info_o[2]) {
    case 1:
        imageGIF($out);
        break;
    case 2:
        imageJPEG($out);
        break;
    case 3:
        imagePNG($out);
        break;
 }

 imageDestroy($out);
 imageDestroy($original);
 imageDestroy($watermark);

 return true;
}

?>
```

В этой конструкции происходит ресайз картинки

`imagecopyresized($thumb, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, $width, $height);`

Ее можно сохранить конструкцией `imagejpeg($thumb, 'photo.jpeg')` и она сохранится с нужным разрешением, но нужно совсем другое, необходимо, чтобы уже уменьшенная картинка попадала вот сюда `imageCopy($out, $thumb, $x, $y, 0, 0, $info_w[0], $info_w[1]);` но этого не происходит... В чем ошибка?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Пока код не приложен - ответ на вопрос будет "сначала ресайзить, а потом накладывать".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем то решил сам свой вопрос!

```
<? 

waterMark($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "watermark.png"); 

function waterMark($original, $watermark) { 


$original = urldecode($original);
   //получаем размеры оригинала и ватермарка в виде массива, где 0 - ширина, 1 - высота, 2 - тип в числе (1-gif, 2-jpeg,3-png), mime - тип для заголовка image/jpeg например
   $info_o = @getImageSize($original); 
   if (!$info_o) 
         return false; 
   $info_w = @getImageSize($watermark); 
   if (!$info_w) 
         return false;
   $original = @imageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($original)); 
   $watermark = @imageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($watermark)); 
   $water_width = imagesx($watermark);
   $water_height = imagesy($watermark);
   //Задаем параметры ширины и высоты ватермарка в зависимости от оригинала
   $percent_w = $info_o[0] * 0.25;
   $percent_h = $info_o[1] * 0.25;
   $water_stamp = imagecreatetruecolor($percent_w, $percent_h);
   header("Content-type: ".$info_o['mime']);
   //Сохраняем прозрачность ватермарка
   imagealphablending( $water_stamp, false );
   imagesavealpha( $water_stamp, true );
   //ресайзим ватермарк
   imagecopyresampled($water_stamp, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $percent_w, $percent_h, $water_width, $water_height);
   //задаем координаты расположения ватермарка от левого края ширина оригинала - ширина ватера - отступ, точно также по высоте начиная с верха
   $x = $info_o[0] - $percent_w - 10;
   $y = $info_o[1] - $percent_h - 10;
   //накладываем ватермарк
   imageCopy($original, $water_stamp, $x, $y, 0, 0, $percent_w, $percent_h);
   //выводим в соответствии с типом файла
   switch ($info_o[2]) { 
      case 1: 
         imageGIF($original); 
         break; 
      case 2: 
         imageJPEG($original); 
         break; 
      case 3: 
         imagePNG($original); 
         break; 
         } 
   //очищаем память
   imageDestroy($original); 
   imageDestroy($watermark);
   imageDestroy($water_stamp); 

   return true; 
   } 

?>
```

Это готовый код. Он будет накладывать водяной знак относительно размеров картинки справа внизу! А теперь если кто подскажет как сделать, чтобы можно было png картинке с прозрачным фоном добавить прозрачности!!! Если делать через Imagecopymerge то появляется черный фон который мы создали через ImageCreateTrueColor, нужно без него!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем еще раз!!! Разобрался как работают некоторые функции php для работы с изображениями, а так же что есть альфа-канал и т.д. Решить вопрос можно следующим образом:
Это убираем

```
imagealphablending( $water_stamp, false );
imagesavealpha( $water_stamp, true );
```

Добавляем следующее:

```
imagecolortransparent ($water_stamp, imagecolorallocate($water_stamp, 0, 0, 0));
```

Здесь мы указываем, что хотим чтобы такой то цвет (в нашем случае черный) был прозрачным...
И меняем imagecopy на imagecopymerge и последним параметром добавляем идентификатор прозрачности

```
imageCopyMerge($original, $water_stamp, $x, $y, 0, 0, $percent_w, $percent_h, 50);
```

Если бы не stackoverflow то ни в коем случае не догадался бы! Спасибо, еще раз!